Rust - как полностью заменить строку?
Не могу понять почему не выводится новое значение строки, которое определяется внутри условия. Внутри условия вывод строки с новым значением работает. Мне нужно именно полностью заменить-пересоздать строку с новым значением по условию.
for line in f.lines(){         
    let line_r = line.expect("Unable to read line");

if re2.is_match(&line_r){
        continue;
    }

if re3.is_match(&line_r){
   // здесь новое значение существует и печатаеся
   let line_r = "2024-05-04 17:33:27,936 NEW string";                        
       println!("{:?}", line_r); 
    }    
   //здесь нет нового значения уже
       println!("{:?}", line_r);  


Сам тупил видимо я.
Вот так получилось. Нужно было ее сделать мутабельной и использовать String::from.
for line in f.lines(){         
    let mut line_r = line.expect("Unable to read line");

if re2.is_match(&line_r){
        continue;
    }

if re3.is_match(&line_r){
        line_r = String::from("2024-05-04 17:33:27,936");                        
    }    
  

    println!("{:?}", line_r); 

